# Svelte and TypeScript how to package a reusable store?

Tags: typescript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

I am new to using Svelte stores. I want to write one and use it in a package I am making. The reason for a store is that it contains state that I want accessible across a few different components. Below is an example of my implementation of something that would be sufficient for my use case. I don't know if this follows convention / best practices.

Will this work as intended?

```js
import { writable, get } from 'svelte/store';
import type { Writable } from 'svelte/store';
import { BROWSER } from 'esm-env';

// NOTE: same as how Svelte-Kit does it under the hood
export const browser = BROWSER

// NOTE: just an example, we will pretend to have an API, but for this example
// we are just reading individual CSV files from /static/data/stocks/*.csv
const DIR_STOCK_FILES = '/data/stocks/'

export const csvStringToRows = (csvString: string, header?: boolean) => {
    const rows = csvString.split('\n')
    return header ? rows.slice(1) : rows;
}

export const parseColumnCSV = (csvString: string, n?: number) => {
    const rows = csvStringToRows(csvString, true)
    return (n ? rows.slice(0, n) : rows).map(row => Number(row))
}

export type StockValueMap = {
    [key: string]: number[]
}

interface GetStockValueURI {
    (symbol: string): string
}

export type StockValue = {
    $STOCKS: StockValueMap
    $API: string;
    getURI: GetStockValueURI;
}

export type WritableStockStore = Writable<StockValue>

interface StockStore extends Writable<StockValue> {
    $STOCKS: StockValueMap
    $API: string;
    getStock:  (symbol: string) => Promise<void>;
    setStock: (symbol: string, value: number[]) => void;

    fetchStockValue: (symbol: string) => Promise<void>;
    numberOfStocks: () => number;
    stockInStore: (symbol: string) => boolean;

    
    setAPI: (api: string) => void;
    getAPI: () => string;

    getURI: (symbol: string) => string;
    setGetURI: (fn: GetStockValueURI) => void;
    
    reset: () => void;
}


const setAPI = (store:StockStore, api: string, debug?:boolean) => {
    if (debug) console.debug('setAPI', store, api)
    store.update((s) => ({...s, $API:api}));
}

const getAPI = (store:StockStore, debug?:boolean) => {
    if (debug) console.debug('getAPI', store, get(store))
    return get(store).$API
}

const getURI = (store:StockStore, stock: string, debug?:boolean) => {
    if (debug) console.debug('getURI', store, stock)
    const api = getAPI(store)
    const uri = `${api}/${stock.toLocaleUpperCase()}.csv`
    return uri    
}

const setGetURI = (store:StockStore, fn:GetStockValueURI, debug?:boolean) => {
    if (debug) console.debug('setGetURI', store, fn)
    store.update((s) => ({...s, getURI:fn}));
}

const fetchStockValues = async (store:StockStore, stock:string, debug?:boolean) => {
    if (debug) console.debug('fetchStockValues', store, stock)
    const uri = getURI(store, stock)
    const res = await fetch(uri);
    const csv = await res.text();
    const data = parseColumnCSV(csv)
    return data
}

export const setStock = (store:StockStore, stock:string, values:number[], debug?:boolean) => {
    if (debug) console.debug('fetchStockValues', store, stock, values)
    store.update(vals => ({
        ...vals, $STOCKS:{...vals.$STOCKS, [stock]: values} 
    }));
}

export const getStock = async (store:StockStore, stock:string, debug?:boolean) => {
    if (debug) console.debug('getStock', store, stock)
    let curr = get(store).$STOCKS;
    // Check if results for this stock are in the store
    if (curr && curr[stock]) {
        console.log(`Values for ${stock} already in store:`, curr[stock]);
        Promise.resolve();
        return curr[stock]
    }

    // NOTE: it values is large (say 20k time points per stock)
    //       it is easy to over-allocate memory in the browser
    // Check if results for this stock are in localStorage
    // const val = getValueFromLocalStroage(stock)
    // if (val !== null && isValuesArray(val)) {
    //     setStock(store, stock, val)
    //     Promise.resolve();
    //     return val
    // } else {
    //     clearValueFromLocalStorage(stock)
    // }

    // Fetch results
    const data = await fetchStockValues(store, stock)
    
    // Store the fetched results in the Svelte store and localStorage
    setStock(store, stock, data)
    // setValueInLocalStorage(stock, data)
    console.log(`Fetched results for ${stock}:`, data);
    Promise.resolve();
    return data
}

const numberOfStocks = (store:StockStore, debug?:boolean) => {
    if (debug) console.debug('numberOfStocks', store)
    return Object.keys(get(store).$STOCKS).length
}

const stockInStore = (store:StockStore, stock:string, debug?:boolean) => {
    if (debug) console.debug('stockInStore', store)
    return get(store).$STOCKS.hasOwnProperty(stock)
}


export const createStockStore = (debug?:boolean) => {
    const store = (writable<StockValue>({} as StockValue))
    const { subscribe, set, update } = store;

    let stst = {
        subscribe,
        update,
        set,
        reset: () => set({} as StockValue),
        $STOCKS: {} as StockValueMap,
        $API: DIR_STOCK_FILES,  // Replace with your directory of stock files.
    } as StockStore;

    stst.setAPI = (api: string) => setAPI(stst, api, debug)
    stst.getAPI = () => getAPI(stst, debug)

    stst.getURI = (symbol: string) => getURI(stst, symbol, debug)
    stst.setGetURI = (fn: GetStockValueURI) => setGetURI(stst, fn, debug)

    stst.setStock = (symbol: string, value: number[]) => setStock(stst, symbol, value, debug)
    stst.getStock = (symbol: string) => getStock(stst, symbol, debug)

    stst.stockInStore = (symbol: string) => stockInStore(stst, symbol, debug)
    stst.numberOfStocks = () => numberOfStocks(stst, debug)

    stst.fetchStockValue = (symbol: string) => fetchStockValue(stst, symbol, debug)
    stst.setAPI(DIR_STOCK_FILES)  // Replace with your directory of stock files.
    return stst
}

let debug = false
const stocks = createStockStore(debug)
export default stocks
```

Comment: We can't run 173 lines of code in our head to evaluate it against how you think it should work. "Will this work as intended?" isn't something we can answer. You wrote that code for a purpose, and and when you use that for that purpose does it work as _you_ intended? If the answer is no, then why not? Maybe we can help you with _that_ question. So do you have a _specific_ question here?

Comment: @AlexWayne yes. How to make a reusable store for a package in svelte. Doing so in Vue can be different than if you're just using it locally.